# How to sort this query correctly?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

[I have this demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140TIfMsNXG4X_DqYcVc4ri1sN8kgBKMJUFT5sKk7dPM/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to sort the query in cell I3 correctly by Column M

I have this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,'30',Col5 where Col5 contains 'Days' Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,'60',Col6 where Col6 contains 'Days' Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,'90',Col7 where Col7 contains 'Days' Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col5",0),""))
```

I have been trying for hours with no luck

I made a tab, expected result, for what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,'30',Col5 where Col5 contains 'Days' Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,'60',Col6 where Col6 contains 'Days' Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,'90',Col7 where Col7 contains 'Days' Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select * where Col1 is not null",0),""), 
VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,'30',Col5 where Col5 contains 'Days' Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,'60',Col6 where Col6 contains 'Days' Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,'90',Col7 where Col7 contains 'Days' Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select Col5 where Col1 is not null",0),""),"\d+"))}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 order by Col6"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

- Strings are sorted lexicographically,i.e., `19 Days` before `2 Days` as 1 < 2
- Remove `Days` from numbers in cols5, 6 and 7 and your query will work fine.
- You can label them later:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,'30',Col5 where Col5 contains 'Days' Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,'60',Col6 where Col6 contains 'Days' Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({A3:G},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,'90',Col7 where Col7 contains 'Days' Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1 is not null format Col5 '0 Days' order by Col5",0),""))
```

- Alternatively, `Days` should be entered in 2 or 3 digits: `19 Days` and `02 Days`.